# Username already taken error and PFUser currentUser

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to update username of `[PFUser currentUser]`.

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser]; user.username = @"New Username";
[user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (completion) {
        completion(succeeded, error);
    }
}];
```

In case, if the username already exist, save method throws an error that "Username already exists". After that, I'm trying to get the original username from `[PFUser currentUser]` but it returns the new username(which is already taken).

And then I'm tried to refresh the object with `refreshObject`

```
[[PFUser currentUser] refreshInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"%@",object);
            }];
```

This method also returns the new username, not the original username.

How to do this? Which is best way to do this?

Comment: If you want to update the username, why do you perform a "sign up" request instead of a "save" one ?

Comment: Sorry Micheal, please check now.

Comment: Have you look at the error code ? if your point is valid, you should receive a 202 error code : kPFErrorUsernameTaken  ( https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFConstants.html ).
Try to do an user query to parse with the new username to see if it's available before assigning it.

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo, you are right about kPFErrorUsernameTaken. And making an query is the only way to do this?

Comment: This is my only guess, i'm not a Parse expert ans can't help you more. Maybe you'll find better help on Parse forums. Sorry for the late answer !